# TypeError: Cannot set property '2' of undefined (line 24, file "Code")

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, undefined, typeerror

I've been trying to figure out this but for the longest time and I've got nothing. How do I fix this error, please help

```
function myFunction() {
  var form = FormApp.openByUrl('form');
  var allItems = form.getItems();
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = doc.getSheetByName("name");
  var last = doc.getLastRow();
  var data = sheet.getRange(1,1,last,8).getValues();

for(i=0,h=1; i<data.length, h<allItems.length;++i,++h){
        
    
    if(data[i][2] == 0 && h==4){ //this where the error messages comes up for the "2"
      
      var newText = allItems[h].asMultipleChoiceItem();
      var title = newText.getTitle();
      var newTitle = newText.setTitle(title+" (Sold out)");
}
}
}
```

Comment: That means that the "data" object is undefined. Check whether the name of the sheet is correct ("name") or the range of the values you are getting ( e.g. var "last"). Could you please add Logger.log(sheet) after the var sheet line?

Answer (score 2):

It means `i` exceeds `data.length`=> `data[i]` will be undefined =>`undefined[2]`: Well,undefined doesn't have  property [2].

> TypeError: Cannot set property '2' of undefined

The "condition" of the for-loop seems amiss. The [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) only returns the last value. Try

```
 i<data.length && h<allItems.length
```

instead.